# Rails , responses get empty sometimes with 201 status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following in one of my controller:

```
      render :json => @obj.to_json, status: 201
```

This is giving empty response **sometimes**, with proper 201 status code.

However if I change the status code to 200, the response is rendered properly everytime.

Any idea why the response body behaviour is behaving like this with the change in status code.

(Note, I am deploying this on heroku - and problem occurs only on server - can't reproduce on local development)

**Edit**:

cURL Details:

curl url syntax is normal with basic headers and some of my own for authentication.

Response:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.21.41.210...
* Connected to utilities-myappp.herokuapp.com (23.21.41.210) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/v2/bookings HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: utilities-myappp.herokuapp.com
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Cookie: request_method=POST
> Connection: keep-alive
> access_token: my-access-token
> Content-Length: 413
> 
* upload completely sent off: 413 out of 413 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
* Server Cowboy is not blacklisted
< Server: Cowboy
< Connection: close
< Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:13:27 GMT
< Status: 201 Created
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Etag: "b7f09a43851971654d269bee8beed023"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 3ed3d9ee-d534-416a-b689-045e1d60e374
< X-Runtime: 0.351844
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
```

This is the same signature I received when 1) I receive the response body(in that case this is followed by response text, 2) when there is no response body.
The only changes are in Date, Etag, X-Request-Id, X-runtime response headers in both cases.

Comment: Reproduce problem with CURL and provide detailed CURL log (-vvvv) here. It will help to investigate problem.

Comment: Very strange that response doesn't have `Content-Length` header. It should be specified in all cases. Are you sure that you don't receive it in success case?